Confidence interval of population variance based on MLE
I am reading Inferences about Normal Linear Models where $Y=\alpha +\beta (x-\bar{x})+\epsilon $ where $\epsilon \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ and i.i.d. The authors calculate all the estimators $\hat{\alpha},\hat{\beta},\hat{\sigma^2}.$ When they calculate the estimate for $\sigma^2$, it comes out be $\hat{\sigma^2}=\frac{1}{n}\sum [Y_i-\hat{\alpha}-\hat{\beta}(x_i-\bar{x})]^2$. Further, they prove that $n\hat{\sigma^2}/\sigma^2\sim \chi_{n-2}^2$. Now my question is when calculating the confidence interval for $\sigma^2$ should we use this Biased estimator $\sigma^2$ or should we go for the unbiased estimator which has a divison by $(n-2)$.
